# How to create a cron job file for export databese for Zurmo CRM?

Tags: php, yii, crm

I am very new in Zurmo crm. i want to create a cron job for take a backup of database of zurmo and also backup of entire site.

Comment: I think you might want to provide more information. This site is meant to solve specific issues, not provide you with complete solutions.

Answer (score 1):

1. change directory `cd /var/www/html/zurmo`
2. zip Zurmo `zip -r Zurmo_bk.zip zurmo`
3. Save db `mysqldump --databases  zurmo > zurmo_bk.sql  -u<login> -p<password>;`